# Change file save directory

Tags: python, urllib

I have a script to download a PDF from a URL working, but it saves it to the same directory the python script is in. I would like to save it to another directory

I've tried changing this with `save_path` however it isn't working, but I also do not get any errors

```
# Import all needed modules and tools
from fileinput import filename
import os
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
import requests

# Disable SSL and HTTPS Certificate Warnings
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

resp = requests.get('url.pdf', verify=False)

response= urllib.request.urlretrieve('url.pdf',
filename = 'civil.pdf')

save_path = "C: my preferred directory"
```

Comment: `save_path` is not located inside any function call, did you mean to place it inside `urllib.request.urlretrieve(...)`?

Comment: If I do this the it says they ( was not closed if it goes onto the third line

Comment: maybe you should use full path in  `filename = "C:\\you_preferred directory\\civil.pdf"` in `urlretrieve()`. And if you want to download with requests them `with open("C:\\you_preferred directory\\civil.pdf", 'wb') as f: f.write(resp.content)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use it directly with `filename`

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('url.pdf',
                           filename='C:\\you_preferred directory\\civil.pdf')
```

And if you want download with `requests`

```
with open("C:\\you_preferred directory\\civil.pdf", 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(resp.content)
```

---

Eventually you should change current directory before downloading

```
os.chdir("C:\\you_preferred directory\\")
```

and then you can use short `filename='civil.pdf'` and `open('civil.pdf', 'wb')`

Comment: if it helped then you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, per comments

```
# Import all needed modules and tools
from fileinput import filename
import os
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
import requests

# Disable SSL and HTTPS Certificate Warnings
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
resp = requests.get('url.org', verify=False)

# Download and name the PDF file from the URL
response= urllib.request.urlretrieve('url.pdf',
filename = 'C:\\ location')

# Save to the preferred directory
with open("C:\\ location", 'wb') as f: f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).